# TS2339: Property 'length' does not exist on type 'string'

Tags: typescript

the following line in my Typescript file:

```
return stringToValidate.length <= maxLength;
```

shows this error: **TS2339: Property 'length' does not exist on type 'string'.**

The code executes fine, but I'm wondering where this problem comes from and how to solve it.

This is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2021",
    "lib": [
      "ES2021"
    ],
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an errant symbol there? For example a character that looks like `e` but is not a Latin `e`. Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: If I paste your code in the TS playground, I can't reproduce the problem: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOdEAoDOUBOMwDmAKnAGoCGANjACblQCmAXItnoQDSIC25AHgBkGhKAAsWYENwBGDHAEpEAbwCwAKESIcDKCBxI2+YmSq16DAHSVhBMYgA8AXh78hI0QG51AXyA)

Comment: This is certainly bizarre; maybe somehow you're not including the TS standard library, but it looks like you are from the tsconfig.  Without a [mre] I don't know how anyone can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this has been only a problem in my IDE. After testing different settings the error was gone.